# Cannot send SMS while using usb modem's internet

Tags: linux, networking, internet, sms, usb-modem

I tried to setting up a simple SMS gateway server with my old Huawei E173 stick using Gammu, I intend to plug in on Raspberry 24/7.

With the help of [this](https://store.createlabz.com/blogs/createlabz-tutorials/huawei-e173-3g-1-2-huawei-e173-setup-send-and-receive-sms-with-raspberry-pi) article, I managed to send my first SMS from Raspberry to my phone, hooray!

The problem is I can't seem to connect to the internet provided from my 3g plan, so to break it down, sending SMS only works when I don't use the modem for internet.

If I tried to sending SMS WHILE connected to the modem's internet, I get this message.

```
gsmsendsms[ERROR]: opening device '/dev/sms' (errno: 16/Device or resource busy)
```

And it seems there was a process using my modem devices.

```
$ sudo lsof /dev/sms
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse file system /run/user/1000/doc
      Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
wvdial  19158 root    4u   CHR  188,0      0t0  557 /dev/ttyUSB0
pppd    19159 root    0u   CHR  188,0      0t0  557 /dev/ttyUSB0
pppd    19159 root    1u   CHR  188,0      0t0  557 /dev/ttyUSB0
pppd    19159 root    2u   CHR  188,0      0t0  557 /dev/ttyUSB0
pppd    19159 root   12u   CHR  188,0      0t0  557 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Obviously I want to be able to do both task, does anyone know how to solve the problem? Is this by design?

Comment: You only have one modem, and it cannot make 2 connections at once.

Comment: @Bib This Q&A suggests otherwise https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166258/3g-modem-simultaneous-sending-sms-and-having-active-internet-connection